# Veins+SUMO Lane Change Behavior

Tags: veins, sumo

I am using Veins (4.7) and SUMO (0.32) to model the lane change behavior in an accident scenario. I successfully create the accident by using below .ini configuration;

```
#Accident vehciles and details
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentCount = 1
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentStart = 80s
*.node[0].veinsmobility.accidentDuration = 100s
```

in which Vehicle-0 starts to stop around 85s.  Now I want to direct the connected vehicles to a specific lane (laneIndex) by using traci command;

```
traciVehicle->changeLane(laneIndex, 0.1);
void TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::changeLane(uint8_t laneIndex, int32_t duration) {
    uint8_t variableId = CMD_CHANGELANE;
    uint8_t variableType = TYPE_COMPOUND;
    int32_t count = 2;
    uint8_t laneIndexT = TYPE_BYTE;
    uint8_t timeT = TYPE_INTEGER;
    int32_t time = duration*1000; //seconds to milliseconds
    uint8_t durationT = TYPE_INTEGER;
    TraCIBuffer buf = connection->query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << variableType << count << laneIndexT << laneIndex << durationT << duration );
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

However, the vehicles do not change the lane. I know the SUMO models the non-accident case so if a vehicle on the target lane or if it is approaching, the lane change is not performed. Do you have any idea how I can get around this behavior? Moreover, if I use traci slowdown command to create randomness to open enough gap for the lane change, then the accident is not performed.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

According to the TraCI documentation for Python the duration is the amount of time the vehicle stays on the other lane, so it is not the time needed to perform the actual lane change.

If this is really the case you might not see the lane change in the UI since your duration is 0.1s and the default SUMO step length in Veins is 0.1s as well.

However, this feature is implemented in the platooning extension for Veins called [Plexe](http://plexe.car2x.org). Here the code to lane the lane via TraCI looks like this:

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::changeLane(int lane, int duration)
{
    uint8_t commandType = TYPE_COMPOUND;
    int nParameters = 2;
    uint8_t variableId = CMD_CHANGELANE;
    TraCIBuffer buf = traci->connection.query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << commandType << nParameters << static_cast<uint8_t>(TYPE_BYTE) << (uint8_t) lane << static_cast<uint8_t>(TYPE_INTEGER) << duration);
    ASSERT(buf.eof());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will give a try and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but don't forget to declare the function in the header file.

```
void TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle::changeLane(int lane, double duration){
uint8_t variableId = CMD_CHANGELANE;
uint8_t variableType = TYPE_COMPOUND;
int32_t count = 2;
uint8_t laneIndexT = TYPE_BYTE;
uint8_t laneIndex = (uint8_t) lane;
uint8_t durationT = TYPE_DOUBLE;
double durationV= double(duration);                                                                             
TraCIBuffer buf = traci->connection.query(CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, TraCIBuffer() << variableId << nodeId << variableType << count << laneIndexT << laneIndex << durationT<< durationV);
ASSERT(buf.eof());}
```